# sum some xml nodes values in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath

Please consider this XML:

```
<Parent ID="p">
    <Child ID="1">10</Child > 
    <Child ID="2">20</Child > 
    <Child ID="3">0</Child > 
</Parent >
```

I want to **SUM** all child value inside the `Parent` node with `ID="p"`.for above example I want query return `30`

How I can do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select @xml.value('sum(/Parent[@ID = "p"]/Child)', 'float') as Sum
```

The use of `float` protects against there being no `Parent` with that `ID`. You can then cast this result to `int`.

Comment: Mark as Answer for `float`.please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145928/strange-behavior-of-sql-server-when-sum-nodes-values-in-xml

Answer (score 4):

Try this :-

```
 Declare @xml xml 
set @xml='<Parent ID="p">
         <Child ID="1">10</Child > 
         <Child ID="2">20</Child > 
         <Child ID="3">0</Child > 
          </Parent >'

 Select @xml.value('sum(/Parent/Child)','int') as Sum
```

Result : `30`

or if you want the sum for a specific `Parent ID` then try the below query

```
 Select @xml.value('sum(/Parent/Child)','int') AS SumVal
 where @xml.exist('/Parent[@ID="p"]') = 1;
```

Demo in [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68aa1/1)

Comment: please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145928/strange-behavior-of-sql-server-when-sum-nodes-values-in-xml

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = '
<Parent ID="p">
    <Child ID="1">10</Child > 
    <Child ID="2">20</Child > 
    <Child ID="3">0</Child > 
</Parent >
<Parent ID="p2">
    <Child ID="1">15</Child > 
    <Child ID="2">20</Child > 
    <Child ID="3">5</Child > 
</Parent >'

SELECT 
      value = SUM(t.value)
    , t.id 
FROM (
    SELECT 
          value = p.value('.', 'INT')
        , id = p.value('./../@ID', 'VARCHAR(50)')
    FROM @XML.nodes('/Parent/Child') t(p)
) t
--WHERE t.id = 'p'
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145928/strange-behavior-of-sql-server-when-sum-nodes-values-in-xml

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
DECLARE @SearchKeyWords XML 

SET @SearchKeyWords =
'<Parent ID=''p''>
    <Child ID="1">10</Child > 
    <Child ID="2">20</Child > 
    <Child ID="3">0</Child > 
</Parent >' 

DECLARE @TempSearchKeyWords TABLE
        (
            SearchKeyWord INT
        )

INSERT INTO @TempSearchKeyWords                     
SELECT SearchKeyWords.SearchKeyword.value('.',' int ') AS SearchKeyword             
FROM @SearchKeyWords.nodes('/Parent/Child') AS SearchKeyWords(SearchKeyword)

SELECT SUM(SearchKeyWord) FROM @TempSearchKeyWords
```

This will return 30.

Comment: please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145928/strange-behavior-of-sql-server-when-sum-nodes-values-in-xml

Comment: ok for that problem please try this answer I have tested with that value it is working fine.