# strange behavior of SQL Server when sum nodes's values in XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I ask a question about sum node's values:

[sum some xml nodes values in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144494/sum-some-xml-nodes-values-in-sql-server-2008?)

Please consider this code:

```
Declare @xml xml 
set @xml='<Parent ID="p">
     <Child ID="1">1000000000</Child > 
     <Child ID="2">234650</Child > 
     <Child ID="3">0</Child > 
      </Parent >'

Select @xml.value('sum(/Parent[@ID="p"]/Child)','bigint') as Sum
```

if you execute this it retrun this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 8
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

the problem is it return this value : `1.00023465E9`

if I change the above query this way it being ok:

```
Declare @xml xml 
set @xml='<Parent ID="p">
     <Child ID="1">1000000000</Child > 
     <Child ID="2">234650</Child > 
     <Child ID="3">0</Child > 
      </Parent >'

Select @xml.value('sum(/Parent[@ID="p"]/Child)','float') as Sum
```

Why Sql Server do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sql Server has a problem converting the value with scientific notation from a string to an integer, as would happen when you run your xpath query, however, it can do this for `float`.

You could write your query like this:

```
select @xml.value('sum(/Parent[@ID = "p"]/Child) cast as xs:long?', 'bigint')
```

Comment: why some of integer should going to be scientific number in sql server?

Comment: This is just how your xpath query, which returns a `number` not an `int` from `sum()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256160.aspx), is returning it to SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @xml XML 
SELECT @xml='<Parent ID="p">
     <Child ID="1">1000000000</Child > 
     <Child ID="2">234650</Child > 
     <Child ID="3">0</Child > 
      </Parent >'

SELECT @xml.value('sum(for $r in /Parent[@ID="p"]/Child return xs:int($r))', 'bigint')
```

**UPDATE:**

```
DECLARE @xml XML 
SELECT @xml='<Parent ID="p">
     <Child ID="1">100000000000000</Child > 
     <Child ID="2">234650</Child > 
     <Child ID="3">0</Child > 
      </Parent >'

SELECT @xml.value('sum(for $r in /Parent[@ID="p"]/Child return xs:decimal($r))', 'bigint')
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
DECLARE @xml XML 
SELECT @xml='<Parent ID="p">
     <Child ID="1">100000000000000.6</Child > 
     <Child ID="2">234650</Child > 
     <Child ID="3">0</Child > 
      </Parent >'

SELECT @xml.value('sum(for $r in /Parent[@ID="p"]/Child return xs:decimal($r))', 'decimal(18,2)')
```

Comment: thanks but it does not work for this: ` <Child ID="1">100000000000000</Child > 
`

Comment: sorry It does not work with floating point numbers.better version is :`CAST(@xml.value('sum(/Parent[@ID="p"]/Child)','float') AS BIGINT)`

Comment: but the main question remains,Why sql do this?

Comment: Update 2: I don't see any problem with floating point numbers.

Comment: Why sql do this? - I agree with the @muhmud answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this is working with BIGINT:

```
DECLARE @SearchKeyWords XML 

SET @SearchKeyWords =
'<Parent ID=''p''>
    <Child ID="1">1000000000</Child > 
    <Child ID="2">234650</Child > 
    <Child ID="3">0</Child > 
</Parent >' 

DECLARE @TempSearchKeyWords TABLE
        (
            SearchKeyWord BIGINT
        )

INSERT INTO @TempSearchKeyWords                     
SELECT SearchKeyWords.SearchKeyword.value('.',' bigint ') AS SearchKeyword             
FROM @SearchKeyWords.nodes('/Parent/Child') AS SearchKeyWords(SearchKeyword)

SELECT SUM(SearchKeyWord) FROM @TempSearchKeyWords
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to know why Sql server can't cast result to `bigint`

Comment: I updated this answer with BIGINT still it's working. please let me know which kind of format you want.

Answer (score 0):

The XML you have here is untyped XML. That means the values provided to `sum()` is of type `xdt:untypedAtomic`. When `sum()` is used on `xdt:untypedAtomic` the values are cast to `xs:double`. The result of `sum()` is read by the `values()` function as a string (or untypedAtomic) and `xs:double` uses the scientific notation when the value is less than 1.0E-6, or greater than or equal to 1.0E6. SQL Server can not convert from scientific notation to `int` or `bigint`.

Ref:
[sum Function (XQuery)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175504.aspx)
[Type Casting Rules in XQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191231.aspx)

Other answers have provided workarounds that cast the input values or the result from `sum()` or using `float` as the data type in `values()`. Another option could be to use typed XML instead.

Schema:

```
create xml schema collection XSDSumTest as '
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Parent">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Child" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:int">
                                <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:int"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>'
```

Query:

```
declare @xml xml(XSDSumTest) = '
<Parent ID="p">
  <Child ID="1">1000000000</Child > 
  <Child ID="2">234650</Child > 
  <Child ID="3">0</Child > 
</Parent>'

select @xml.value('sum(/Parent[@ID="p"]/Child)','bigint') as Sum
```