# Get data from parent xml which has different child xml tags in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xquery, xquery-sql

I have an xml whose parent tag have different child tags based on it modelType.
All I want is to get those different child tags data in a single Select query.

Here is the my xml

```
<rateModelList>
        <rateModel>
            <intRateModelID>1</intRateModelID>
            <strName>Gra - Base Model</strName>
            <intModelTypeID>1</intModelTypeID>          
            <totalVolumeTiersList>
                <totalVolumeTiers>
                    <decIncentiveRate>0.50</decIncentiveRate>
                    <decMaxValue>19.00</decMaxValue>
                    <decMinValue>0.00</decMinValue>                                 
                </totalVolumeTiers>             
            </totalVolumeTiersList>
        </rateModel>
        <rateModel>
            <intRateModelID>2</intRateModelID>
            <strName>Ges - Special</strName>
            <intModelTypeID>3</intModelTypeID>          
            <participationTiersList>
                <participationTiers>
                    <decIncentiveRate>0.50</decIncentiveRate>
                    <decMaxValue>19.00</decMaxValue>
                    <decMinValue>0.00</decMinValue>                                 
                </participationTiers>               
            </participationTiersList>
            <dollarBasedTiersList>
                <dollarBasedTiers>
                    <decIncentiveRate>0.50</decIncentiveRate>
                    <decMaxValue>19.00</decMaxValue>
                    <decMinValue>0.00</decMinValue>                             
                </dollarBasedTiers>             
            </dollarBasedTiersList>
        </rateModel>
        <rateModel>
            <intRateModelID>5</intRateModelID>
            <strName>G2 - participation</strName>
            <intModelTypeID>2</intModelTypeID>          
            <participationTiersList>
                <participationTiers>
                    <decIncentiveRate>0.50</decIncentiveRate>
                    <decMaxValue>19.00</decMaxValue>
                    <decMinValue>0.00</decMinValue>                 
                </participationTiers>               
            </participationTiersList>
        </rateModel>
    </rateModelList>
```

All I want is to get all data in single select query.

Here is my query, that is not working as required

```
Declare @planBean xml = '<rateModelList>
        <rateModel>
            <intRateModelID>1</intRateModelID>
            <strName>Gra - Base Model</strName>
            <intModelTypeID>1</intModelTypeID>          
            <totalVolumeTiersList>
                <totalVolumeTiers>
                    <decIncentiveRate>0.50</decIncentiveRate>
                    <decMaxValue>19.00</decMaxValue>
                    <decMinValue>0.00</decMinValue>                                 
                </totalVolumeTiers>             
            </totalVolumeTiersList>
        </rateModel>
        <rateModel>
            <intRateModelID>2</intRateModelID>
            <strName>G - Special</strName>
            <intModelTypeID>3</intModelTypeID>          
            <participationTiersList>
                <participationTiers>
                    <decIncentiveRate>0.50</decIncentiveRate>
                    <decMaxValue>19.00</decMaxValue>
                    <decMinValue>0.00</decMinValue>                                 
                </participationTiers>               
            </participationTiersList>
            <dollarBasedTiersList>
                <dollarBasedTiers>
                    <decIncentiveRate>0.50</decIncentiveRate>
                    <decMaxValue>19.00</decMaxValue>
                    <decMinValue>0.00</decMinValue>                             
                </dollarBasedTiers>             
            </dollarBasedTiersList>
        </rateModel>
        <rateModel>
            <intRateModelID>5</intRateModelID>
            <strName>Ges - participation</strName>
            <intModelTypeID>2</intModelTypeID>          
            <participationTiersList>
                <participationTiers>
                    <decIncentiveRate>0.50</decIncentiveRate>
                    <decMaxValue>19.00</decMaxValue>
                    <decMinValue>0.00</decMinValue>                 
                </participationTiers>               
            </participationTiersList>
        </rateModel>
    </rateModelList>'
SELECT 
      t.c.value('(strName/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)') as strName
    , t.c.value('(intModelTypeID/text())[1]', 'int') as intModelTypeID
    , s.c.value('(decMinValue/text())[1]', 'decimal(17,4)') as decMinValue_totalVolumeTiers
    , r.c.value('(decMinValue/text())[1]', 'decimal(17,4)') as decMinValue_participationTiers
    , u.c.value('(decMinValue/text())[1]', 'decimal(17,4)') as decMinValue_dollarBasedTiers
FROM @planBean.nodes('rateModelList/rateModel') t(c)
CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('./totalVolumeTiersList/totalVolumeTiers') s(c)
CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('./participationTiersList/participationTiers') r(c)
CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('./dollarBasedTiersList/dollarBasedTiers') u(c)
```

Result Required

```
-------   --------------   -----------
strName | intModelTypeId | decMinValue
-------   --------------   -----------
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use OUTER APPLY instead of CROSS APPLY?

```
SELECT 
  t.c.value('(strName/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)') as strName
, t.c.value('(intModelTypeID/text())[1]', 'int') as intModelTypeID
, ( SELECT min(x) FROM ( VALUES (s.c.value('(decMinValue/text())[1]','decimal(17,4)')) , (r.c.value('(decMinValue/text())[1]','decimal(17,4)')) , (u.c.value('(decMinValue/text())[1]','decimal(17,4)')) ) AS val(x) ) as decMinValue
    FROM @planBean.nodes('rateModelList/rateModel') t(c)
    OUTER APPLY t.c.nodes('./totalVolumeTiersList/totalVolumeTiers') s(c)
    OUTER APPLY t.c.nodes('./participationTiersList/participationTiers') r(c)
    OUTER APPLY t.c.nodes('./dollarBasedTiersList/dollarBasedTiers') u(c)
```

Otherwise you can use a union of three queries:

```
SELECT strName, intModelTypeID, min(decMinValue) decMinValue
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 
          t.c.value('(strName/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)') as strName
        , t.c.value('(intModelTypeID/text())[1]', 'int') as intModelTypeID
        , u.c.value('(decMinValue/text())[1]', 'decimal(17,4)') as decMinValue
    FROM @planBean.nodes('rateModelList/rateModel') t(c)
    CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('./dollarBasedTiersList/dollarBasedTiers') u(c)
    UNION
    SELECT 
          t.c.value('(strName/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)') as strName
        , t.c.value('(intModelTypeID/text())[1]', 'int') as intModelTypeID
        , r.c.value('(decMinValue/text())[1]', 'decimal(17,4)') as decMinValue
    FROM @planBean.nodes('rateModelList/rateModel') t(c)
    CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('./participationTiersList/participationTiers') r(c)
    UNION
    SELECT 
          t.c.value('(strName/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)') as strName
        , t.c.value('(intModelTypeID/text())[1]', 'int') as intModelTypeID
        , s.c.value('(decMinValue/text())[1]', 'decimal(17,4)') as decMinValue
    FROM @planBean.nodes('rateModelList/rateModel') t(c)
    CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('./totalVolumeTiersList/totalVolumeTiers') s(c)
    ) sbt
    GROUP BY strName, intModelTypeID
```

Both solutions are feasible only if you have a reduced and defined number of *Tiers*.

Comment: yes I think Union will work for me because I need to get data of decMinValue in a same column.

Comment: Also the first solution can be used to obtain a single column.
I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard in your XQuery to get to the `decMinValue` element and you can do the aggregate in the XQuery as well.

```
select M.X.value('(strName/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)') as strName,
       M.X.value('(intModelTypeID/text())[1]', 'int') as intModelTypeID,
       M.X.value('min(*/*/decMinValue/text()) cast as xs:decimal?', 'decimal(17,4)') decMinValue
from @planBean.nodes('/rateModelList/rateModel') as M(X);
```

An explanation on why there is a cast to xs:decimal can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162083/569436).