# How to sum all xml nodes values, in the deepest hierarchy of the doc, using xpath to xml column in sql server, without using nodes names?

Tags: sql-server, xpath

I have an xml field in sql server, and I want to sum all nodes values in the deepest level, using xpath.

For example, in this scheme:

```
<c>
  <b1>
    <a>1</a>
    <d>4</d>
    <g>5</g>
 </b1>
 <b1>
   <a>7</a>
   <d>1</d>
   <g>2</g>
 </b1>
</c>
```

I need to get the sum of all node values under "b1".
All nodes names may change from one xml to another, and also the location of "b1" in the hierarchy level.

So basically, I need to be able to get to the deepest node, and all its siblings, and sum all.

In this example, the sum I expect to get is: 20.

I need the xpath expression look like this:

```
xmlData.value('sum(.......)', 'float')
```

And one more thing: Is there a way to eliminate a certain node from the sum?
Say I want all, except node "a"..

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding float data type when you really mean something like decimal (12,2). You're going to have to deal with all the stupid decimal places that float estimates to down the road.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum some xml nodes values in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144494/sum-some-xml-nodes-values-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: No, you probably failed to understand my needs. No node name mention required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generic xpath to select all nodes and, later, cast it as `int`:

```
DECLARE @data XML = '
        <NewDataSet>
          <b1>
            <a>1</a>
            <d>4</d>
            <g>5</g>
         </b1>
         <b1>
           <a>7</a>
           <d>1</d>
           <g>2</g>
         </b1>
        </NewDataSet>'

SELECT  SUM(t.c.value('(text())[1]', 'INT'))    -- cast their value as INT
FROM    @data.nodes('//*') t(c)                 -- all elements, no matter their name
```

EDIT:

```
select  @data.value('sum(//*[not(*)])', 'float')
```

Comment: if you only want the deepest nodes without children, use `//*[not(*)]`; you're supposed to sum them with SQL, not XPath

Comment: I fail to understand how this doesn't meet your need; can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Its part of a large query, and the calculation should look like: xmlData.value('sum(.......)', 'float')

Comment: Great Rubens, its exactly what I needed!

Comment: ask a new question ;)

Comment: I just created one another :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023948/eliminate-a-xml-node-from-sum-in-xpath-to-sql-server-xml-column