# Eliminate a xml node from sum, in XPath to SQL Server XML column

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I have this XPath expression, which sum all nodes in the deepest XML hierarchy, without using nodes names:

```
select  @data.value('sum(//*[not(*)])', 'float')
```

How do I make an exception of one node, by its name?

Say this is the xml:

```
<c>
  <b1>
    <a>1</a>
    <d>4</d>
    <g>5</g>
 </b1>
 <b1>
   <a>7</a>
   <d>1</d>
   <g>2</g>
 </b1>
</c>
```

I would like the sum to contain "d" and "g", without "a", but "a" will be pass as parameter and so need to be represented as parameter inside the expression. I've tried the following:

```
declare @except varchar(max) = 'a'


select  @data.value('sum(//*[not(*)])', 'float') - @data.value('sum(//*:local-name()=sql:variable("@except"))', 'float')
```

but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Marc's answer is what i would do mostly, I have a small hack for you, below

```
select  @data.value('sum(//*[not(*)])', 'float')- @data.value('sum(//*:a)', 'float')
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. I added just another little requirement. Be happy if you would adjust by it.

Comment: I think there's no place for creating another question on this. Please try to adjust your answer by my last requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the XML into name and value in a CTE, and then select from that CTE - something like this:

```
DECLARE @Data XML = '...(your XML here).....';

;WITH XmlCte AS
(
    SELECT
        NodeName = xc.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(25)'),
        NodeValue = xc.value('(.)[1]', 'int')
    FROM 
        @Data.nodes('/c/b1/*') AS XT(XC)
)
SELECT SUM(x.NodeValue)
FROM XmlCte x
WHERE x.NodeName <> 'a'
```